# Watir and storing code in a variable

Tags: ruby, variables, watir

I have stored Watir syntax in a global variable under the tag of `Err_Rout`.
The code I have stored is accessible as I can print it out in the command prompt window, and it does work generically.

What I want to do is call the tag in the script and then script runs this code. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this? is it even possible?

Here is my stored syntax-

```
if browser.text.include?("Error") 
  then print "\n\nFail\t" 
  else print "\n\nPass\t" 
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There are a number of tools that provide assertion hooks and create reports (e.g. MiniTest, rspec).  They take some time to learn, but it certainly pays off.

Comment: I want to create a sub routine with that specific syntax and then call the subroutine several times in the script. This will then check for the text 'error' and then send the results to me via command prompt window. Thanks for those suggestions I will do some research into them.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who wants to know its -

```
def errorSearch(obj,rgn)
  if obj.text.include?("Error") then
     obj.screenshot.save ("#{rgn}_Error.png")
     print  "\n\nI have Found an Error...Dont Panic!!!\t" 
 else
     print "\n\nNo Error Found\t" 
 end  
end
```

And to call the method -

```
errorSearch(browser,region)
```

Cheers